# React Redux (within a single file) not calling render() after store changed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, redux

I am trying to create a simple example of a React Redux file to demonstrate a change after retrieving data from an API.  The reducer is definitely creating a new state to return but the render() is not called.  Is the render() only called in child components within the Provider tag; ie. it will not call the render() of the component the Provider is defined in?

Any help would be appreciated, have been looking through documentation for hours.. :-(

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

import './App.css';

const DELAY = 10000;
const initialState = { count: 0, fact: "" };


class App extends React.Component
{
  reducer( state = initialState, action )
  {
    console.log( 'reducer', state, action );
    let newState = {};

    switch( action.type )
    {
      case "UPDATE":
        newState = { count: state.count + 1, fact: action.fact };
        console.log( 'newState', newState );
        break;

      default:
        newState = {...state};
    }

    return newState;
  }

  store = createStore( this.reducer );

  async getNumberFact( number )
  {
    const response = await axios.get(`http://numbersapi.com/${number}/math`);
    return response;
  }

  componentDidMount()
  {
    setInterval( () =>
    {
      this.getNumberFact( this.store.getState().count )
      .then( (response) =>
      {
        this.store.dispatch( { type: "UPDATE", fact: response.data } );
      } )
      .catch( (error) =>
      {
        console.log( `Totally got this error: ${error}`);
      } );

    }, DELAY );
  }

  render()
  {
    return(
      <Provider store={this.store}>
        <div>
          {console.log( this.store.getState() )}
          <p>{this.store.getState().count}</p>
          <p>{this.store.getState().fact}</p>
        </div>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: [jmargolisvt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59572710/1218980) is right. Your `App` component is not registered to the store changes, which is what [_react-redux's_ `connect` HoC](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect) does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An update happens when a component's state or props change.  Your `render` function has neither.  I would expect `{this.store.getState().count}` to run on mount and then never again.  Your component has no props and there is no reference to `this.state`.  Referring to `this.store` is not the same thing and the component-local state.  It's the redux store --in an unconventional place, I might add-- and the component does not directly respond the redux store.  This is what methods like `mapStateToProps` are for.

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#updating

https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapstate